# Why does my Socket client only receive 1 packet?

Tags: java, sockets

I have a chess server and client that I made in Java that transfers packets to each other. When a client connects, the server sends a packet back to the client. My program always detects this packet. After that when I try to move a piece, a packet is sent to the server and the server detects it. It prints the packet string to the client which the client uses to move the piece, but the client never reads it. How do I fix this?

Connection superclass:

```
public class ChessConnection {
protected Socket socket;
protected PrintWriter output;
protected BufferedReader input;

public void listen() {
    try {
        String line;
        while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
            this.inputReceived(line);
        }
    } catch (SocketException e) {
        System.out.println("SocketException: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("IOException: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void sendPacket(Packet packet) {
    output.println(packet.serialize());
};

public void inputReceived(String input) {}
}
```

ClientConnection (Client side):

```
public class ClientConnection extends ChessConnection {
public ClientConnection() {
    try {
        socket = new Socket("localhost", 4141);
        output = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    } catch (HeadlessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.out.println("Host is unknown");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    new Thread(this::listen).start();
}

@Override
public void listen() {
    try {
        String line;

        while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println("client received input: " + line); // This doesn't print the move piece packet, but it does print the connection packet
            this.inputReceived(line);
        }
    } catch (SocketException e) {
        System.out.println("SocketException: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("IOException: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

ServerConnection (Server side):

```
public class ServerConnection extends ChessConnection {
private static int NEXT_ID = 1;
private static ArrayList<ServerConnection> clients = new ArrayList<ServerConnection>();

public int connectionId;
public ServerHandler handler;

public ServerConnection(ServerHandler handler, Socket socket) {
    this.connectionId = NEXT_ID++;
    this.handler = handler;

    try {
        this.socket = socket;
        this.output = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        this.input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    new Thread(this::listen).start(); // Starts listening to client

    System.out.println("Client " + this.connectionId + " connected");
    sendPacket(new ConnectionPacket());
}

@Override
public void listen() {
    try {
        String line;
        while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
            this.inputReceived(line);
        }
    } catch (SocketException e) {
        System.out.println("SocketException: " + e.getMessage());
        handler.broadcastPacket(new DisconnectionPacket());
        System.out.println("Client " + this.getId() + " disconnected");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("IOException: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void inputReceived(String input) {
    System.out.println("server received input: " + input);
    Packet packet = Packet.toPacket(input);

    switch (packet.getType()) {
    case Packet.DISCONNECTION:
        break;
    case Packet.CONNECTION:
        break;
    case Packet.PIECE_MOVE:
        System.out.println("sending move piece");
        handler.broadcastPacket(packet);
        break;
    case Packet.PAWN_REPLACEMENT:
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("Received malformed packet: " + input);
        break;
    }
}

public int getId() {
    return this.connectionId;
}

public static ServerConnection getClientFromId(int clientId) {
    for (ServerConnection client : clients) {
        if (client.getId() == clientId) {
            return client;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
}
```

Comment: Are you sending packets or lines? Or does each of your packets contain exactly one line? What protocol are you using to send these packets? UDP?

Comment: Each packet is one line. The packets are converted like this: `public String serialize() {

  return this.type + "|" + startPos.serialize() + "|" + targetPos.serialize();

 }`
I believe I am using UDP

Comment: How is that a line? There's no newline at the end. Doesn't the definition of a line pretty much require a terminating newline?

Comment: I'm using the println method from PrintWriter to print to the socket output on both ends. Would it make any difference if I added a newline to the end of the string I'm sending?

Comment: Oh, I see. Are you using TCP? It sounds like this has nothing to do with packets at all. (These are, in fact, messages.)

Comment: I believe I am using TCP. I haven't set it to use tcp or udp so whatever the default is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143114/discussion-between-treehousefalcon-and-david-schwartz).